# PHP, Using the explode function during writing in Xml file error

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to write some locations into an xml file in order to use them later it was working until I decide to use explode it gives me then an error which is:"error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."Here is the code:

```html
<?php 
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "thecode007", "007","offers") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM Branches";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysql_error());

 $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
$node = $doc->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$node = $doc->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
$loc=explode(",",$row);
$newnode->setAttribute("location", $loc[0]);
}

print $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

Comment: Try to remove `?>` at the file end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with explode:

```
$loc=explode(",",$row);
```

$row **is** an array already. Explode is used to split strings into arrays. 
This is difficult without seeing what the data returned for the query is, but assuming you want the entire first column of your result to be $loc, then just remove the explode() call and replace with:

```
$loc = $row[0];
```

Note, this is super-bad. You should replace the * in your select with the names of actual columns. In this form your program is very brittle because a change to the first column would change what info is being stored in $loc.

ps. and yes, remove the ?> at the end of the file, but that was not the problem.

Comment: thnx man,the data was a location coordinate from Google map I'm saving them for using them to develop dynamic map marker from data base.